# How to use workManager concept using in jboss server

Tags: java

I want to use JbossWorkManagertTaskExecutor for workManager Concept.Could you please any one advice.

1.How to use workManager concept using in jboss server.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 2):

As [Justin Brentam suggested](https://developer.jboss.org/message/718053#718053) below

> To be clear,
>   org.springframework.jca.work.jboss.JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor treats
>   the JBoss javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager implementation as if it
>   was an implementation of [JSR-237](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237).  This is clear from the [Spring
>   documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jca/work/jboss/JBossWorkManagerTaskExecutor.html) which states, "This is the JBoss equivalent of the
>   CommonJ WorkManagerTaskExecutor adapter for WebLogic and WebSphere." 
>   To my knowledge, this statement in inaccurate.  Our
>   javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager implementation is for JCA resource
>   adapters (implied by the fact that javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager
>   is part of the JCA API) and not a general work manager as envisaged by
>   JSR-237.  Although it was technically possible to get a reference to a
>   javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager implementation in previous
>   versions of JBoss AS it was never designed for this.

For more, you can go through [this tutorial](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/169380?start=15&tstart=0)